# Combine Toad sql queries with decreasing output results into one list

Tags: toad

I've been trying to produce a result where multiple queries return more restrictive returns. How can I see the full list as well as those records that meet the more restrictive conditions? Query 1 returns 538 records of sites in the given counties.

```
SELECT E_SITES.ID "SITE ID",
E_SITES.NAME "SITE NAME",
E_SITES.ADDR_1 "SITE ADDRESS"
E_SITES.CITY_NAME || ', ' || E_SITES.STATE_CODE || ' ' || E_SITES.POSTAL_CODE,
E_SITES.COUNTY_NAME
FROM E_SITES
WHERE E_SITES.COUNTY_NAME IN ('ALLAMAKEE', 'BENTON', 'BLACK HAWK', 'BREMER', 'BUCHANAN', 'CHICKASAW', 'CLAYTON', 'DELAWARE', 'DUBUQUE')
ORDER BY E_SITES.ID
```

Query 2 returns the number of sites that have a contact person identified. This is 503 records.

```
SELECT E_SITES.ID "SITE ID",
E_SITES.NAME "SITE NAME",
E_SITES.ADDR_1 "SITE ADDRESS"
E_SITES.CITY_NAME || ', ' || E_SITES.STATE_CODE || ' ' || E_SITES.POSTAL_CODE,
E_SITES.COUNTY_NAME,
E_INDIVIDUALS.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || E_INDIVIDUALS.LAST_NAME
FROM E_SITES, E_AFFILIATIONS, E_INDIVIDUALS
WHERE E_SITES.SITE_ID = E_AFFILIATIONS.SITE_ID
AND E_AFFILIATIONS.INDIVIDUAL_RID = E_INDIVIDUALS.RID
AND E_AFFILIATIONS.AFFILIATION_TYPE = ('SITE_CONTACT')
AND E_SITES.COUNTY_NAME IN ('ALLAMAKEE', 'BENTON', 'BLACK HAWK', 'BREMER', 'BUCHANAN', 'CHICKASAW', 'CLAYTON', 'DELAWARE', 'DUBUQUE')
ORDER BY E_SITES.ID
```

A further query would return those sites with a mailing address, which reduces the results down to 486 records. I need to get all 538 records, whether or not they have a contact or mailing address, and for those that do, have one row for each site.

**Additional Information**
My current results can look like this for Query 1 (including column headers for clarity, quotes to distinguish data elements):
"SITE ID" "SITE NAME"      "SITE ADDRESS" "CITY, STATE ZIP"      "COUNTY_NAME"
"09698" "BODINE ELECTRIC" "18114 KAPP DR" "PEOSTA, IA 52067"      "BREMER"
"16895" "BRUGGEMAN LUMBER" "3003 WILLOW RD" "HOPKINTON, IA 52237"  "DELAWARE"
"40047" "GENEVIEVE, LLC"   "707 LINCOLN ST"  "GARNAVILLOR, IA 52052"  "CLAYTON"

Query 2 which requires a contact person currently only returns records that meet the requirement, even though I use the (+) operator.
"SITE ID" "SITE NAME"      "SITE ADDRESS" "CITY, STATE ZIP"      "COUNTY_NAME" "FIRST NAME LAST NAME"
"40047" "GENEVIEVE, LLC"   "707 LINCOLN ST"  "GARNAVILLOR, IA 52052"  "CLAYTON" "DALE KARTMAN"

I get 1 record rather than the 3 records, with 2 having no contact person and 1 with a contact person. This is my dilema. I have to run each of these queries separately, get the results and copy them to a spreadsheet. Then I have to align the records with contact names to the 1st query of all facilities. Very labor intensive. Hope this helps clarify my needs.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, it is the `OUTER JOIN` you're looking for.

Here's a simple example (based on Scott's EMP and DEPT tables) which shows what it is.

There are 4 departments in the DEPT table:

```
SQL> select deptno from dept order by deptno;

    DEPTNO
----------
        10
        20
        30
        40
```

However, no employee works in department 40:

```
SQL> select deptno, ename from emp order by deptno;

    DEPTNO ENAME
---------- ----------
        10 KING
        10 CLARK
        10 MILLER
        20 FORD
        20 SMITH
        20 JONES
        30 JAMES
        30 TURNER
        30 MARTIN
        30 WARD
        30 ALLEN
        30 BLAKE

12 rows selected.

SQL>
```

If you want to display information collected from both of those tables (department name from the DEPT table and employee name from the EMP table), you'd join those tables - just like you did (I'll use ANSI syntax which actually *JOINS* tables, instead of enumerating them and putting join conditions into the WHERE clause):

```
SQL> select d.deptno, d.dname, e.ename
  2  from dept d join emp e on e.deptno = d.deptno
  3  order by d.deptno;

    DEPTNO DNAME          ENAME
---------- -------------- ----------
        10 ACCOUNTING     KING
        10 ACCOUNTING     CLARK
        10 ACCOUNTING     MILLER
        20 RESEARCH       FORD
        20 RESEARCH       SMITH
        20 RESEARCH       JONES
        30 SALES          JAMES
        30 SALES          TURNER
        30 SALES          MARTIN
        30 SALES          WARD
        30 SALES          ALLEN
        30 SALES          BLAKE

12 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Looks OK, but - I'd like to get information about DEPTNO = 40, although nobody works in it. So, use outer join:

```
SQL> select d.deptno, d.dname, e.ename
  2  from dept d left join emp e on e.deptno = d.deptno
  3  order by d.deptno;

    DEPTNO DNAME          ENAME
---------- -------------- ----------
        10 ACCOUNTING     KING
        10 ACCOUNTING     CLARK
        10 ACCOUNTING     MILLER
        20 RESEARCH       FORD
        20 RESEARCH       SMITH
        20 RESEARCH       JONES
        30 SALES          JAMES
        30 SALES          TURNER
        30 SALES          MARTIN
        30 SALES          WARD
        30 SALES          ALLEN
        30 SALES          BLAKE
        40 OPERATIONS

13 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Right! Here it is! (note that LEFT JOIN produces the same result as LEFT OUTER JOIN; no need to specify "outer", although it makes thinks somewhat more obvious).

Also, there's the "old" Oracle outer join operator, `(+)` (literally, a + sign enclosed into round brackets). The above query would work as well if we put it like this:

```
select d.deptno, d.dname, e.ename
from dept d, emp e
where d.deptno = e.deptno (+);
```

I'd suggest you do the same with (outer join) your query. Once again:

- join tables in the JOIN clause
- put filters into the WHERE clause

Query will be easier to read and maintain, you'll know what is what, and - if necessary (and it might even be the case for you), if you use the "old" (+) operator, you won't be able to outer join one table to more than just one another table. As you're going deeper and deeper, you might need to outer join some table to several others, and that's where ANSI join takes place.

Good luck!